# Correct way to check Java version from BASH script

Tags: java, bash, version, dependency-management

How can I check whether Java is available (in the PATH or via JAVA_HOME) from a bash script and make sure the version is at least 1.5?

Comment: Java 5 has been end-of-life for quite a long time. Java 6 will be end-of-life very soon. You should be moving to Java 6 as a priority, and to 7 as soon as you can.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried)

Comment: @Brian: Nothing; My hope is that someone has a "bash search path function" handy.

Comment: @kittylyst: This is a minimal requirement. My software doesn't need Java 6 features, so there is no point forcing users for something better. But thanks for pointing it out anyway.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
if type -p java; then
    echo found java executable in PATH
    _java=java
elif [[ -n "$JAVA_HOME" ]] && [[ -x "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java" ]];  then
    echo found java executable in JAVA_HOME     
    _java="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
else
    echo "no java"
fi

if [[ "$_java" ]]; then
    version=$("$_java" -version 2>&1 | awk -F '"' '/version/ {print $2}')
    echo version "$version"
    if [[ "$version" > "1.5" ]]; then
        echo version is more than 1.5
    else         
        echo version is less than 1.5
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Excellent. I was missing the `type` builtin.

Comment: Ug sorry cant get comments to format.  This fails when Java version is 1.10.  This is because string comapre is not a number compare.  Also the answer is wrong when version is "1.5"  Though I guess that would be "1.5.0" so I guess its okay.

Comment: good point. you could do something like: `IFS=. read major minor extra <<<"$version"; if (( major == 1 && minor > 5 )); ...` -- would have to check for invalid octal numbers like "08".

Comment: the "`type -p java`" won't work in "sh"; so, for portability, use `#!/bin/bash` in the script, rather than `#!/bin/sh` (though, it's possible that `/bin/sh` isn't actually bourne shell, but rather a backward compatible variant)

Comment: For comparing versions, I suggest : `version1=$(echo "$version" | awk -F. '{printf("%03d%03d",$1,$2);}')` which will get you major and minor aligned with 3 digit for each, and then compare with `if [ $version1 -ge 001008 ] ; then`

Comment: Combining Glenn's original post with his comment above, I did the following to check for Java <=1.7 (in this case related to setting TLS defaults:
`IFS=. read major minor extra <<<$(java -version 2>&1 | awk -F '"' '/version/ {print $2}');
if [ $major -lt 1 -o $major -eq 1 -a $minor -le 7 ]; then
  JVM_EXTRA_OPTS="-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1";
fi`

Comment: Boo, hiss for showing a string comparison instead of a version comparison.

Answer (score 53):

You can obtain java version via:

```bash
JAVA_VER=$(java -version 2>&1 | awk -F '"' '/version/ {print $2}' | awk -F '.' '{sub("^$", "0", $2); print $1$2}')
```

it will give you `16` for java like `1.6.0_13`,  `15` for version like `1.5.0_17`, `110` for `openjdk 11.0.6 2020-01-14 LTS` and `210` for `java version 21 2023-09-19 LTS`.

So you can easily compare it in shell:

```bash
[ "$JAVA_VER" -ge 15 ] && echo "ok" || echo "too old"
```

**UPDATE:**
This code should work fine with openjdk and `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: The result of 'java -version' with OpenJDK 8 is slightly different, "java" is replaced by "openjdk" in the output. This expression works with both cases: `sed 's/.*version "\(.*\)\.\(.*\)\..*"/\1\2/; 1q'`

Comment: If JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS is set the output is again slightly different, the java version is not on the first line. eg: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentlib:hprof
java version "1.7.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)
Dumping Java heap ... allocation sites ... done

Comment: EmmanuelBourg and codebuddy thanks. I updated code to fix issues you found.

Comment: This doesn't work correctly anymore since java 9, and fails spectacularly since java 10

Comment: Some tweak to this as below should work after Java 9 as well...

JAVA_VER=$(java -version 2>&1 | sed -n ';s/.* version "\(.*\)\.\(.*\)\..*"/\1\2/p;')

Answer (score 30):

The answers above work correctly only for specific Java versions (usually for the ones before Java 9 or for the ones after Java 8.

I wrote a simple one liner that will return an integer for Java versions 6 through 11 (and possibly all future versions, until they change it again!).

It basically drops the "1." at the beginning of the version number, if it exists, and then considers only the first number before the next ".".

`java -version 2>&1 | head -1 | cut -d'"' -f2 | sed '/^1\./s///' | cut -d'.' -f1`

Answer (score 17):

You can issue `java -version` and read & parse the output

```
java -version 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep 'java version' | awk '{print $3}'
```

Comment: This is very close to what I want. Do you know of a version which also searches `$PATH` before it calls `locate` (which isn't always available)?

Comment: both links dont work and I checked my internet twice :-)

Comment: @Ravi, right I will edit those links, you could use `java -version 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep 'java version' | awk '{print $3}'` by the time

Comment: If interested in the numerical part only and for further usage in path variables, you may use something like `java -version 2>&1 | head -1 | cut -d '"' -f 2`

Answer (score 11):

You could also compare the jdk class version number with `javap`:

```
javap -verbose java.lang.String | grep "major version" | cut -d " " -f5
```

If its java 8, this will print 52, and 55 for java 11. With this you can make a simple comparison and you don't have to deal with the version string parsing.

Comment: This is a nice hack if you just want to know the major version. Sometimes, you'd like to check that a certain patchlevel is installed.

Comment: Amazing, this is bullet proof !!

Comment: Simple and easy for major version check

Answer (score 9):

I wrote a bash function that should work for JDK 9 and JDK 10.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# returns the JDK version.
# 8 for 1.8.0_nn, 9 for 9-ea etc, and "no_java" for undetected
jdk_version() {
  local result
  local java_cmd
  if [[ -n $(type -p java) ]]
  then
    java_cmd=java
  elif [[ (-n "$JAVA_HOME") && (-x "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java") ]]
  then
    java_cmd="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
  fi
  local IFS=$'\n'
  # remove \r for Cygwin
  local lines=$("$java_cmd" -Xms32M -Xmx32M -version 2>&1 | tr '\r' '\n')
  if [[ -z $java_cmd ]]
  then
    result=no_java
  else
    for line in $lines; do
      if [[ (-z $result) && ($line = *"version \""*) ]]
      then
        local ver=$(echo $line | sed -e 's/.*version "\(.*\)"\(.*\)/\1/; 1q')
        # on macOS, sed doesn't support '?'
        if [[ $ver = "1."* ]]
        then
          result=$(echo $ver | sed -e 's/1\.\([0-9]*\)\(.*\)/\1/; 1q')
        else
          result=$(echo $ver | sed -e 's/\([0-9]*\)\(.*\)/\1/; 1q')
        fi
      fi
    done
  fi
  echo "$result"
}

v="$(jdk_version)"
echo $v
```

This returns `8` for Java 8 (`"1.8.0_151"` etc), and `9` for Java 9 (`"9-Debian"` etc), which should make it easier to do the further comparison.

Answer (score 5):

Determining the Java version only using grep with Perl-style regex can be done like this:

```sh
java -version 2>&1 | grep -oP 'version "?(1\.)?\K\d+'
```

This will print the major version for Java 9 or higher and the minor version for versions lower than 9, for example `8` for Java `1.8` and `11` for Java `11.0.4`.

It can be used like this:

```sh
JAVA_MAJOR_VERSION=$(java -version 2>&1 | grep -oP 'version "?(1\.)?\K\d+' || true)
if [[ $JAVA_MAJOR_VERSION -lt 8 ]]; then
  echo "Java 8 or higher is required!"
  exit 1
fi
```

The `|| true` was added to prevent the script from aborting in case Java is not installed and the Shell option `set -e` was enabled.

Answer (score 4):

A combination of different answers:

```
JAVA_VER=$(java -version 2>&1 | grep -i version | sed 's/.*version ".*\.\(.*\)\..*"/\1/; 1q')
```

- Returns `7` for Java 7 and `8` for Java 8
- Works with OpenJDK and with Oracle JDK
- Works even if the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS is set

Comment: for Java 10, this returns '0' for the version number

Comment: $ java -version 2>&1 | grep -i version | sed 's/.*version ".*\.\(.*\)\..*"/\1/; 1q'
--> 0
for java version "9.0.1"

Comment: Indeed, answer below works better for java version > 9: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56243046/3193604

Answer (score 3):

1. in TERMINAL

```
java -version |& grep 'version' |& awk -F\" '{ split($2,a,"."); print a[1]"."a[2]}'
```

2. in BASH

```
#!/bin/bash


echo `java -version 2>&1 | grep 'version' 2>&1 | awk -F\" '{ split($2,a,"."); print a[1]"."a[2]}'`
jver=`java -version 2>&1 | grep 'version' 2>&1 | awk -F\" '{ split($2,a,"."); print a[1]"."a[2]}'`

if [[ $jver == "1.8" ]]; then                
     echo $jver is java 8
else
     echo $jver is java 11
fi
```

Works in SUN and Linux

Comment: Small improvements: Use `$(...)` instead of backticks. They are safer, support nesting, and easier to type on most keyboards/OSs.

Answer (score 2):

The method I ended up using is:

```
# Work out the JAVA version we are working with:
JAVA_VER_MAJOR=""
JAVA_VER_MINOR=""
JAVA_VER_BUILD=""

# Based on: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32026447
for token in $(java -version 2>&1 | grep -i version)
do
    if [[ $token =~ \"([[:digit:]])\.([[:digit:]])\.(.*)\" ]]
    then
        JAVA_VER_MAJOR=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        JAVA_VER_MINOR=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
        JAVA_VER_BUILD=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
        break
    fi
done
```

It will work correctly even if JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS is set to something due to filtering done by grep.

Comment: Oneliner: `if [[ $(java -version 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep 'java version' | awk '{print $3}') =~ \"([0-9])\.([0-9])\.([0-9])_(.*)\" ]]; then echo ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}; fi`

Answer (score 2):

Another way is:
A file called `release` is located in `$JAVA_HOME`.
On Java 15 (Debian) it has as content:

```
IMPLEMENTOR="Debian"
JAVA_VERSION="15.0.1"
JAVA_VERSION_DATE="2020-10-20"
MODULES="java.base java.compiler java.datatransfer java.xml java.prefs java.desktop java.instrument java.logging java.management java.security.sasl java.naming java.rmi java.management.rmi java.net.http java.scripting java.security.jgss java.transaction.xa java.sql java.sql.rowset java.xml.crypto java.se java.smartcardio jdk.accessibility jdk.internal.vm.ci jdk.management jdk.unsupported jdk.internal.vm.compiler jdk.aot jdk.internal.jvmstat jdk.attach jdk.charsets jdk.compiler jdk.crypto.ec jdk.crypto.cryptoki jdk.dynalink jdk.internal.ed jdk.editpad jdk.hotspot.agent jdk.httpserver jdk.incubator.foreign jdk.internal.opt jdk.jdeps jdk.jlink jdk.incubator.jpackage jdk.internal.le jdk.internal.vm.compiler.management jdk.jartool jdk.javadoc jdk.jcmd jdk.management.agent jdk.jconsole jdk.jdwp.agent jdk.jdi jdk.jfr jdk.jshell jdk.jsobject jdk.jstatd jdk.localedata jdk.management.jfr jdk.naming.dns jdk.naming.rmi jdk.net jdk.nio.mapmode jdk.sctp jdk.security.auth jdk.security.jgss jdk.unsupported.desktop jdk.xml.dom jdk.zipfs"
OS_ARCH="x86_64"
OS_NAME="Linux"
SOURCE=""
```

So you see `JAVA_VERSION`, which contains the version number.

For example,

```
major=$(echo $JAVA_VERSION | cut -d. -f1)
```

sets `major` to the value 15 (=Major version number), which you can use further.

It's a really simple solution.

Comment: Interesting. I found the file in several JDKs (Oracle and OpenJDK). I don't think it will exist in J9 or the Amazon JVM. Plus you need to figure out the Java installation folder if `$JAVA_HOME` isn't defined.

Answer (score 2):

Getting java version string, using Bash's built-in parsing capabilities:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

java_cmd=${1:-java}

# Captures version string between double-quotes
IFS='"' read -r _ java_version_string _ < <("${java_cmd}" -version 2>&1)

# Splits version string at dots and (underscore for patch number)
IFS='._' read -r \
  java_version_major \
  java_version_minor \
  java_version_build \
  java_version_patch \
  <<<"$java_version_string"

# Debug demo output
declare -p java_version_major java_version_minor java_version_build \
  java_version_patch
```

**Examples**

System default Java 17:

```bash
declare -- java_version_major="17"
declare -- java_version_minor="0"
declare -- java_version_build="3"
declare -- java_version_patch=""
```

Specific Java 8 path provided as argument:

```bash
declare -- java_version_major="1"
declare -- java_version_minor="8"
declare -- java_version_build="0"
declare -- java_version_patch="352"
```

Comment: I''m getting `-bash: java_version_major: command not found` for the line with the here string `<<<`.

Comment: `IFS="." read java_version_major java_version_minor java_version_build java_version_patch   <<< "$java_version_string"` works for me.

Comment: @AaronDigulla I broke my answer with an unfortunate cut during an edit. It is now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, I wanted to check which version of java was installed to perform two types of application launches.
The following code has solved my problem

```
jdk_version() {
  local result
  local java_cmd
  if [[ -n $(type -p java) ]]
  then
    java_cmd=java
  elif [[ (-n "$JAVA_HOME") && (-x "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java") ]]
  then
    java_cmd="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
  fi
  local IFS=$'\n'
  # remove \r for Cygwin
  local lines=$("$java_cmd" -Xms32M -Xmx32M -version 2>&1 | tr '\r' '\n')
  if [[ -z $java_cmd ]]
  then
    result=no_java
  else
    for line in $lines; do
      if [[ (-z $result) && ($line = *"version \""*) ]]
      then
        local ver=$(echo $line | sed -e 's/.*version "\(.*\)"\(.*\)/\1/; 1q')
        # on macOS, sed doesn't support '?'
        if [[ $ver = "1."* ]]
        then
          result=$(echo $ver | sed -e 's/1\.\([0-9]*\)\(.*\)/\1/; 1q')
        else
          result=$(echo $ver | sed -e 's/\([0-9]*\)\(.*\)/\1/; 1q')
        fi
      fi
    done
  fi
  echo "$result"
}

_java="$(jdk_version)"
echo $_java

if [[ "$_java" > "$8" ]]; then
       echo version is more than 8

else
  echo version is less than 8

fi
```

[source](http://eed3si9n.com/detecting-java-version-bash)

*I hope to be proved helpful*

Comment: You should be able to replace the `sed` with BASH parameter expansion (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) using `${parameter/pattern/string}`

Comment: @AaronDigulla Thanks for the information, I will see the link and I update the answer

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice portable bash function for this here: http://eed3si9n.com/detecting-java-version-bash

```
jdk_version() {
  local result
  local java_cmd
  if [[ -n $(type -p java) ]]
  then
    java_cmd=java
  elif [[ (-n "$JAVA_HOME") && (-x "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java") ]]
  then
    java_cmd="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
  fi
  local IFS=$'\n'
  # remove \r for Cygwin
  local lines=$("$java_cmd" -Xms32M -Xmx32M -version 2>&1 | tr '\r' '\n')
  if [[ -z $java_cmd ]]
  then
    result=no_java
  else
    for line in $lines; do
      if [[ (-z $result) && ($line = *"version \""*) ]]
      then
        local ver=$(echo $line | sed -e 's/.*version "\(.*\)"\(.*\)/\1/; 1q')
        # on macOS, sed doesn't support '?'
        if [[ $ver = "1."* ]]
        then
          result=$(echo $ver | sed -e 's/1\.\([0-9]*\)\(.*\)/\1/; 1q')
        else
          result=$(echo $ver | sed -e 's/\([0-9]*\)\(.*\)/\1/; 1q')
        fi
      fi
    done
  fi
  echo "$result"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old thread but this will still be of help to others.

To know whether you're running Java 5, 6 or 7, firstly type `java -version`.

There will be a line in your output that looks similar to this: **java version "1.7.0_55"**

Then you use this table for converting the 'jargon' result to the version number.

1.7.0_55 is Java 7
1.6.0_75 is Java 6
1.5.0_65 is Java 5

Information taken from a page on the Oracle site
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u55-relnotes-2177812.html

Comment: This doesn't work if you have anything other than those specific minor versions of Java, e.g.

Comment: Well. I got this information from a page on the official Oracle site. I don't know it all and neither do I pretend to. If you know what other versions of Java there are then feel free to add a subcomment with these underneath this message.

Comment: 1.5.0_anything is Java 5, 1.6.0_anything is Java 6, 1.7.0_anything is Java 7, 1.8.0_anything is Java 8. The minor versions change all the time (though I suppose there aren't ever going to be any new ones for Java 5 or 6).

Comment: Also, there's no guarantee anyone will have the most recent minor version.

Comment: That's fair enough. Why didn't you just say that in the first place? I had a feeling that 1.x... meant version x but I didn't want to make that assumption in case I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Using bashj, an extended bash version (https://sourceforge.net/projects/bashj/), you get a rather compact solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/bashj
echo System.getProperty("java.runtime.version")
```

The answer is provided by an integrated JVM (in ~0.017''  execution time for the script , and ~0.004'' for the call itself).

Answer (score 0):

I found the following works rather well. It is a combination of the answers from [Michał Šrajer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7335120/4215616) and [jmj](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7334780/4215616)

`version=$(java -version 2>&1 | sed -n ';s/.* version "\(.*\)\.\(.*\)\..*"/\1\2/p;' | awk '{ print $1 }')`.

I have openJDK 13 installed and without the `awk` command the first answer printed: `130 2020-01-14`. Thus, adding `awk '{ print $1 }'` provides me with just the version.

Answer (score 0):

This question is still relevant so posting my answer.

Using slightly convoluted way by using built-in Bash variable expansions and avoiding creating multiple sub-shells

```
line=$(java -version 2>&1 | head -1) && echo ${${${line#*\"}#1.}%%.*}
```

Returns 8 for Java 1.8.0_312 and 17 for 17.0.6

This can be used in a script like below

```
#!/bin/bash

required=5

version=$(line=$(java -version 2>&1 | head -1) && echo ${${${line#*\"}#1.}%%.*})

[[ $version -ge $required ]] && echo "Java version OK" || echo "Java version too low"
```