# How to fetch Java version using single line command in Linux

Tags: linux, parsing, version

I want to fetch the Java version in Linux in a single command.

I am new to awk so I am trying something like

```
java -version|awk '{print$3}'
```

But that does not return the version.  How would I fetch the `1.6.0_21` from the below Java version output?

```
java version "1.6.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_21-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0-b16, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 91, accepted):

1. Redirect stderr to stdout.
2. Get first line
3. Filter the version number.

   ```
   java -version 2>&1 | head -n 1 | awk -F '"' '{print $2}'
   ```

Comment: Less one process: `java -version 2>&1|awk -F\" '/version/ {print $2}'

Comment: @holygeek: & John: the command fails in `AIX` machine saying `awk: can't open {print$2}`. What could be the problem?

Comment: @Simon: this could be the quote escaping issue.

Comment: `java -version 2>&1 | head -n 1 | awk -F '"' '{print $2}' | awk -F '.'  '{print $2}'` if you just want the major version number.

Comment: Heads up: if `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` in in the environment, the version will not be on the first line, breaking this command.

Answer (score 10):

This is a slight variation, but PJW's solution didn't quite work for me:

```
java -version 2>&1 | head -n 1 | cut -d'"' -f2
```

just cut the string on the delimiter `"` (double quotes) and get the second field.

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest using `grep -i version` to make sure you get the right line containing the version string.  If you have the environment variable JAVA_OPTIONS set, openjdk will print the java options before printing the version information.  This version returns 1.6, 1.7 etc.

```
java -version 2>&1 | grep -i version | cut -d'"' -f2 | cut -d'.' -f1-2
```

Answer (score 2):

Since (at least on my linux system) the version string looks like "1.8.0_45":

```
 #!/bin/bash
 function checkJavaVers {
    for token in $(java -version 2>&1)
    do
        if [[ $token =~ \"([[:digit:]])\.([[:digit:]])\.(.*)\" ]]
        then
            export JAVA_MAJOR=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
            export JAVA_MINOR=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
            export JAVA_BUILD=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
            return 0
        fi
    done
    return 1
}

#test
checkJavaVers || { echo "check failed" ; exit; }
echo "$JAVA_MAJOR $JAVA_MINOR $JAVA_BUILD"
~
```

Comment: Nice, but on older versions of bash, the RE should be quoted:

`if [[ $token =~ "\"([[:digit:]])\.([[:digit:]])\.(.*)\"" ]]`

Comment: I'm not using an older version of bash, and that's not my dog.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `--version` and in that case it's not required to redirect to stdout

```
java --version | head -1 | cut -f2 -d' '
```

From java help

```
-version      print product version to the error stream and exit
--version     print product version to the output stream and exit
```

Comment: Which operating systems and which Java versions? Does not work on Ubuntu 16.04 and Java 8.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my variation (with thanks/acknowledgements to many answers prior to this).  My goal is to produce a "Major Version" in line with [JEP 223](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/223).  Assumption are made; I don't know if it works across the board for all released (or to be released) versions of java.

```
java -version 2>&1 | fgrep -i version | cut -d'"' -f2 | sed -e 's/^1\./1\%/' -e 's/\..*//' -e 's/%/./'
```

| Version | Results |
| --- | --- |
| 1.6.0_65 | 1.6 |
| 1.8.0_282 | 1.8 |
| 11.0.10 | 11 |
| 15.0.2 | 15 |

Answer (score 0):

This way works for me.

```
# java -version 2>&1|awk '/version/ {gsub("\"","") ; print $NF}'

1.8.0_171
```

Answer (score 0):

```
java -version 2>&1 | head -1 | awk -F '_|"' '{print $2}'
```

Output

```
1.8.0
```

Or

```
java -version 2>&1 | head -1 | awk -F '_|"' '{print $2}' | cut -c 1-3
```

Output

```
1.8
```

Answer (score -1):

Getting only the "major" build #:

```
java -version 2>&1 | head -n 1 | awk -F'["_.]' '{print $3}'
```