# Testing for installed Apache Maven

Tags: bash, maven, maven-3

i found this question ([Correct way to check Java version from BASH script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334754/correct-way-to-check-java-version-from-bash-script)). I am unsure how to do the same for Apache maven. I have to make sure for an installation script that at least version 3.1.1 of Maven is installed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it that way, cause prerequisites is deprecated with Maven 3.

```
  <!-- The following is marked as deprecated with Maven 3. so using maven-enforcer-plugin instead. -->
  <!--  http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-4840 -->
  <!--  http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5297 -->
  <prerequisites>
    <maven>${mavenVersion}</maven>
  </prerequisites>
  (...)
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>enforce-maven</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>enforce</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <rules>
            <requireMavenVersion>
              <version>${mavenVersion}</version>
            </requireMavenVersion>
          </rules>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maven has a feature to declare minimum maven version in the POM itself. You don't need to add any other check after you add this to your POM:

```
<prerequisites>
    <maven>3.1.1</maven>
</prerequisites>
```

See [Prerequisites](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Prerequisites) in maven documentation.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I know this feature, but i want to check the version in a bash script. ;)

Comment: @Marcello90 I am wondering what may be the reason for doing that in bash script?

Comment: Its for the installation of an application. I call maven from a bash script. Without maven or with the wrong version it makes no sense to start the installation procedure, so i want to test this at the start of the bash script.