# Check if Java Installed with Bash

Tags: java, bash

Can someone tell me why this simple command cannot find the output "java version"?

```
if java -version | grep -q "java version" ; then
  echo "Java installed."
else
  echo "Java NOT installed!"
fi
```

output from `java -version` is as follows

```
java version "1.8.0_77"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode)
```

Comment: You're not actually checking the output or version, so is there a reason why you don't just use `which`?

Comment: Why grep for the version, when you could just check if the binary itself exists and is executable?

Comment: Binary is not in the same place on every machine, wouldn't be sound to test src.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334754/correct-way-to-check-java-version-from-bash-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your java is openJDK then you can use following options

```
java -version 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep "java version\|openjdk version"
```

or you can make more generic by

```
java -version 2>&1 >/dev/null | egrep "\S+\s+version"
```

to get java version

```
JAVA_VER=$(java -version 2>&1 >/dev/null | egrep "\S+\s+version" | awk '{print $3}' | tr -d '"')
```

Comment: egrep is nonstandard, probably better so do grep -E "\S+\s+version"

Comment: java_version=$(java -version 2>&1 | awk -F '"' '/version/ {print $2}')

Answer (score 8):

`java` outputs to STDERR. You can use

```
if java -version 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep -q "java version" ; then
```

but probably simpler to do something like

```
if [ -n `which java` ]; then
```

Comment: I noticed `which` is not always available from testing this software on multiple machines from the get go to see what is available. Why I was testing the java command. Thanks for the time.