# Correct way to check Javac version in BASH script

Tags: bash, javac

I am trying to get the javac version in a bash script (intended for apks manipulation and builds).

I found a way to get the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334754/correct-way-to-check-java-version-from-bash-script) version which may be similar but not the same (it does not work for javac).

P.S.: Currently working on OS X but should also work on Linux.

EDIT: PS: Some environments may not have javac in the PATH

Thanks!

Comment: `javac -version` seems to work just fine when `javac` is in the `PATH`. What is your specific problem?

Comment: we can't help you fix your code if you don't include it in your Q. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this function that supports both cases, when javac is or is not in PATH variable

```
showJavacVersion() 
{
    x="h"
    {
        x=$(type -p javac)
    } >&-
    if [ -n "$x" ]; then
        _javac=javac
    elif [[ -n "$JAVA_HOME" ]] && [[ -x "$JAVA_HOME/bin/javac" ]];  then
        _javac="$JAVA_HOME/bin/javac"
    fi
    if [[ "$_javac" ]]; then
        version=$("$_javac" -version 2>&1 | awk -F ' ' '/javac/ {print $2}')
        echo $version
    else
        echo javac not found
    fi
}
```

Simply call it this way

```
showJavacVersion
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: The JAVA_HOME thing did the trick. It happened because I needed to run this in environments with no "install" but copied SDKs.

Answer (score 0):

If `javac` in the `PATH`:

```
jc_ver="$(javac -version 2>&1| grep -o '[0-9_.]*$')"
echo "$jc_ver"
```

Or using `cut`:

```
jc_ver="$(javac -version 2>&1| cut -d ' ' -f2)"
```

Comment: Also using awk jc_ver=$(javac -version 2>&1 | awk -F ' ' '/javac/ {print $2}')