# Comparing two Java versions number string and install newer one

Tags: shell

In shell script I want to compare the system Java version with another Java version which I want and install if both are not same. I tried by using

```
java -version  
head -1 file | cut -d' ' -f3
VERSION='1.8.0_1'
if [ $output -lt $VERSION ]then
sudo apt-get install default-jre
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to check Java version from BASH script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334754/correct-way-to-check-java-version-from-bash-script)

Comment: Ya,got it.Thank you Julien Lopez.