# How to display the current java version of host servers using loop in ansible

Tags: ansible

I need to display the current java version using the loop in ansible. Currently i am able to fetch and display the same on the host server but when i need to pass the same values in another play it does not works there.
Below is the playbook -
Question is what exactly needs to be changed in the localhost play so that we can get the values of of java version , and in case in future if we add or remove any host server in that case no coding changes must be required as it must be in loop.

```
Host inventory  -

[testserver]
zlp12037 ansible_ssh_host=zlp12037.vci.att.com ansible_ssh_user=abc
zlp12036 ansible_ssh_host=zlp12036.vci.att.com ansible_ssh_user=abc

---
- hosts: testserver
  tasks:
- name: Fetch Java Version
  shell: java -version 2>&1 | grep    version | awk '{print $3}' | sed 's/"//g'
  register: result
- debug: msg="{{item}}:{{result.stdout}}"
  with_items: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"

- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
- debug: var=hostvars['item']['result']['stdout']
  with_items: groups['inventory_hostname']

Result: 

 TASK [Fetch Java Version]  ******************************************************
 changed: [zlp12037]
 changed: [zlp12036]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [zlp12037] => (item=zlp12037) => {
  "item": "zlp12037",
  "msg": "zlp12037:1.8.0_66"
}
ok: [zlp12036] => (item=zlp12036) => {
  "item": "zlp12036",
  "msg": "zlp12036:1.8.0_66"
}


PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=groups['inventory_hostname']) => {
    "hostvars['item']['result']['stdout']": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!",
    "item": "groups['inventory_hostname']"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0        failed=0
zlp12036                   : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
zlp12037                   : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `with_items` must be templated
2. `object['item']` fetch item with literal name `item`, while `object[item]` fetch item with name from variable named `item`
3. `groups[inventory_hostname]` will try to find group named `localhost` in your case

I guess, you want:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug: var=hostvars[item]['result']['stdout']
      with_items: "{{ groups['testserver'] }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run a bash script to execute and store the Java version value in a file which you can read in the ansible playbook.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7335524/7328096

```
            if type -p java; then
                echo found java executable in PATH
                _java=java
            elif [[ -n "$JAVA_HOME" ]] && [[ -x "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java" ]];  
 then
                echo found java executable in JAVA_HOME     
                _java="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
            else
                echo "no java"
            fi

            if [[ "$_java" ]]; then
                version=$("$_java" -version 2>&1 | awk -F '"' '/version/ 
  {print $2}')
                echo version "$version"
                if [[ "$version" > "1.5" ]]; then
                    echo version is more than 1.5
                else         
                    echo version is less than 1.5
                fi
            fi
```