# Get the Java version in specific format using bash

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell

My Java version is:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_312"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_312-b07)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.312-b07, mixed mode)
```

How can I get the Java version in below format using bash script:
1.8.0

I tried multiple options like `java -version 2>&1 | head -n 1 | cut -d'"' -f2`, but I'm unable to get the desired output.

Comment: what do you need the version for?

Comment: There may be useful information about that in https://stackoverflow.com/q/7334754/10871900 (although that's mainly about the major version)

Comment: @criztovyl I want to check if exact matching version i.e "1.8.0" exists on my machine or not. I referred many stackoverflow content however unable to get the desired result.

Comment: do you need to extract the version or is it enough to know it is that version?

Comment: @criztovyl It is enough to know if that is the version

Comment: You are already close: The command you posted here returns you `1.8.0_312`. Store this string into a variable and remove everything starting with the underscore character from the variable. See the section titled _Parameter Expansion_ in the bash man page.

Answer (score 3):

To check for a string (your expected version), you can use grep:

```
if java -version 2>&1 | head -n 1 | grep --fixed-strings '"1.8.0'
then echo expected version
else echo unexpected version
fi
```

Note the `--fixed-strings` (short `-F`), otherwise grep treats `.` as a RegEx and it will match any character. Thx Gorodon for pointing that out!
I also added the leading `"` quote so it will not match `11.8.0`.

Comment: `grep` treats its argument as a regular expression, meaning that "." will match any character. It also only looks for a match *somewhere* in a line, meaning it'll match substrings. These mean it could match things that're radically different from what you'd expect, like "11.8.0" or "1.850.5".

Comment: Argh, true! I'll add `-F`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ IFS='"_' read -r _ ver _ < <(java -version 2>&1)
$ echo "$ver"
1.8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
java --version | head -n1 |cut -d " " -f1,2
```

**output**

```
openjdk 8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *grep* (or *egrep*) to print matching patterns:

```
java --version | head -n 1 | grep -Po '[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}'     
java --version | head -n 1 | egrep -o '[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}'
```