# E: Package 'lib32gcc1' has no installation candidate

Tags: ubuntu-22.04

I installed the UR-Sim file (https://www.universal-robots.com/download/software-cb-series/simulator-linux/offline-simulator-cb-series-linux-ursim-1816941tarqz/). Im Using Ubuntu 22.04.

When i run `$ ./install.sh` i recived the error `$ Installed java version is too old, exiting`
so i replaced in install.sh the needToInstallJava() function

```
needToInstallJava() {
    echo "Checking java version"
    if command -v java; then
    # source https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334754/correct-way-to-check-java-version-from-bash-script
        version=$(java -version 2>&1 | awk -F '"' '/version/ {print $2}')

    echo "Stripping the front end"
    majorVersion=${version%%.*}
        echo Java major version "$majorVersion"
    if [ "`echo "$majorVersion > 1.6" | bc`" -eq 1 ]; then
        echo "java version accepted"
            return 0
    fi
    fi
    return 1
}
```

When i run with the changed file `$ ./install.sh` i get following output.

```
Checking java version
/usr/bin/java
Stripping the front end
Java major version 11
java version accepted
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libjava3d-java-doc' for glob 'libjava3d-*'
Note, selecting 'libjava3d-jni' for glob 'libjava3d-*'
Note, selecting 'libjava3d-java' for glob 'libjava3d-*'
Note, selecting 'ttf-dejavu-core' for glob 'ttf-dejavu*'
Package lib32gcc1 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  lib32gcc-s1

Package libcurl3 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libcurl4:i386 libcurl4

E: Package 'lib32gcc1' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libcurl3' has no installation candidate
```

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Source of the problem

In the `install.sh` script, the following two lines are problematic on the `Ubuntu 22.04` distro:

```
sudo apt-get install -y lib32gcc1 libc6-i386
sudo dpkg -i urtool/*.deb
```

The problem arises because the package `lib32gcc1` was renamed to `lib32gcc-s1` in this distro's repos.
In the second line, the `urtool/*.deb` (`urtool/urtool3_0.3_amd64.deb`) has `lib32gcc1` as a dependency. As the dependency is not present, `dpkg` refuses to install the package.

### Solution by editing the `.deb` file

In order to fix this, you can edit the `.deb` file to have `lib32gcc-s1` as a dependency instead of `lib32gcc1`. First, you should install the `lib32gcc-s1` package.

---

***Note for similar problems to this one***: This approach would not work if the binaries inside the dependency packages changed names. You can check this with:

```
dpkg -L lib32gcc-s1 | xargs file
```

Which shows the following output:

```
/.:                         directory
/usr:                       directory
/usr/lib32:                 directory
/usr/lib32/libgcc_s.so.1:   ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=bc9d0c313ce683defc25191bac6f913fa197d2d1, stripped
/usr/share:                 directory
/usr/share/doc:             directory
/usr/share/doc/lib32gcc-s1: symbolic link to gcc-12-base
```

There's only one executable in this package - namely, `libgcc_s.so.1`.
If you check the [content of `lib32gcc1`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/amd64/lib32gcc1/filelist) package, you will find identically named file there. (If you wanted to be completely sure the executables are the same, you could compare their `md5` checksums or look into source code and see if there were any changes since the package rename.)

---

#### Analyzing the `.deb` file

A `.deb` file is just an `ar` archive file that contains the data relevant for installing the package: executables, installation instructions, dependencies, metadata, etc. To extract the archive data, `cd` into `urtool` and run:

```
ar x urtool3_0.3_amd64.deb
```

You should be able to see the following list of files: `control.tar.gz`, `data.tar.gz`, `debian-binary`. Dependency data is contained inside `control.tar.gz`.

#### Unpacking `control.tar.gz`

Let's create new directory and extract the control archive there:

```
mkdir extras-control
tar -C extras-control -zxf control.tar.gz
```

You should see the following list of files inside `extras-control`: `conffiles`, `control`, `md5sums`, `postinst`, `postrm`, `shlibs`.
Dependency info is inside the `control` file. Open it with your text editor of choice and change the line:

```
Depends: lib32gcc1, ...
```

to

```
Depends: lib32gcc-s1, ...
```

#### Packing it back up

Now that the dependency is changed, first pack up the unpacked `.tar` directory, and then move it to the outer directory:

```
tar cfz control.tar.gz *
mv control.tar.gz ..
```

Then, in the outer directory, using `ar` pack up the following files into a new `.deb` package with:

```
ar r new_urtool3.deb debian-binary control.tar.gz data.tar.gz
```

Finally, install your new package:

```
sudo dpkg -i new_urtool3.deb
```